# Is it unprofessional to resign again after accepting a counter-offer?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, ethics, resignation, negotiation

3 months ago I resigned from my current position because I got a better package at a similar-level organization. By similar-level organization, I mean that they have around the same revenue, employees, and project technology as my previous organization.

My employer wanted to retain me and offered to match the package I was getting at the other organization, and I accepted it and stayed with the same employer and rejected the offer from the new employer.

In the matching offer, we have agreed to a commitment of 1 year of engagement with my current organization, otherwise the raise will be rolled back and I need to give back the difference when I leave.

Now, I am being offered an even better package than I got three months ago from a new third organization, that is very broad is a multinational company.

I have resigned again based on this offer. Now, as per the agreement, I need to return the pay difference for what I got these past three months. I am agreeing to give back this difference because it will be recovered from the new employer after a few months.

Now, please let me know, is this an unprofessional way to resign again from my current employer?

Comment: What country/region?

Answer (score 15):

> *Please let me know is this a unprofessional way to resign again from my current employer?*

No, not if you fulfill the leaving "criterion" you agreed upon.

To justify, it will be problematic both for you and your employer to stay in a good working relationship if you have a feeling you are being  underpaid and have a better chance elsewhere. Better to part of good terms.

**No one wants to be in a losing relationship.**

Answer (score 10):

**It is not unprofessional**, as it is acting as per contract. Obviously the company even expected it to some degree, as they've asked for the clause to hand back part of your payment in such a case (personally, I'd find that asking for such a clause is a grounds to look for other work in the first place as it shows there is no mutual trust in wanting to work together).

However, it **likely will burn some bridges** with your old company with respect to returning short to mid-term at least.

Comment: If OP has accepted twice offers to quit the first company, returning to said company is probably not his/her main concern.

Comment: @Nyakouai not saying that it is, that's for OP to decide. OP's question was about perception, and while it's not per se unprofessional it can have similar results with respect to this one company at least.

Answer (score 2):

Not unprofessional to leave for better payment, specially if you've been only for a short period in a company. As @FrankHopkins mentioned, it does burn a few bridges.

Keep in mind however, that if you hop between jobs too often you might have little to speak about each of them, and you will not have completed meaningful projects and have deliveries of your own.

An experienced employee with no deliveries is a big red flag.

Another red flag is the possibility that you switch jobs too often because you've caused problems in every place you've been.

Keep in mind that for now you are OK, but those red flags should start becoming a concern for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not unprofessional in the sense that you're honoring the contract.

It might be seen as unprofessional from the perspective that other employers may see you as being indecisive, fickle, unreliable, and professionally immature for making these moves in such a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really care if it’s professional or unprofessional. What you want to know is whether it will impact your career negatively.

Well, there’s a company that won’t take you back. There will be a small number of employees who will remember you. There’s a second company slightly less annoyed. It’s up to you to decide how likely it will affect your career, and if a better job is worth it.